# How to resolve this erros "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Requested partitioning does not match the tablename table" in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

While writing data into hive partitioned table, I am getting below error.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Requested partitioning does not match the tablename table:

I have converted my RDD to a DF using case class and then I am trying to write the data into the existing hive partitioned table. But I am getting his error and as per the printed logs "Requested partitions:" is coming as blank. Partition columns are coming as expected in the hive table.

## spark-shell error :-

scala> data1.write.format("hive").partitionBy("category", "state").mode("append").saveAsTable("sampleb.sparkhive6")

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Requested partitioning does not match the sparkhive6 table:

Requested partitions:

Table partitions: category,state

## Hive table format :-

hive> describe formatted sparkhive6;

OK

col_name              data_type               comment

txnno                   int
txndate                 string
custno                  int
amount                  double
product                 string
city                    string
spendby                 string

Partition Information

col_name              data_type               comment

category                string
state                   string

Answer (score 2):

Try with **`insertInto()`** function instead of **`saveAsTable()`**.

```
scala> data1.write.format("hive")
.partitionBy("category", "state")
.mode("append")
.insertInto("sampleb.sparkhive6")
```

**`(or)`**

Register a **temp view on top of the dataframe** then write with sql statement to insert data into hive table.

```
scala> data1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_vw")
scala> spark.sql("insert into sampleb.sparkhive6 partition(category,state) select txnno,txndate,custno,amount,product,city,spendby,category,state from temp_vw")
```

Comment: Thanks for providing both the options, however I m getting below error while running the 1st option:- "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: insertInto() can't be used together with partitionBy(). Partition columns have already been defined for the table. It is not necessary to use partitionBy()". As per the error log suggested I removed the partitionBy() columns and it worked fine.
Also could you please clarify why saveAsTable() function is not working in this case, yes we can go with the other options, but need to understand why the error is coming while using saveAsTable() function.

Comment: @Bis, there are some issues with df.saveAsTable with spark2(community working on this issue).. for more details: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html#ki_sparksql_dataframe_saveastable